# I can't edit music on my ipod

Tags: itunes, windows, ipod-nano

I was using ipod nano and itunes on my previous computer. Now I have new computer with itunes. But when I connect my ipod it doesn't show the sync button. The connection is working, but when I click on Music in itunes it doesn't show me the sync button. There is only a list of all of the music on iPod and I can play it, but I cant delete it or add new music. There is a button edit playlist, but even if I click it I still can't edit the music on my ipod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you using an older version of iTunes on the old computer? They have made a number of redesigns in how iTunes works. If you see a little iPod icon show up near the top of the iTunes window below the play button when you connect the iPod, click it, and then at the bottom click Sync. Or go to File>Devices>Sync.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I didn't know I have to click the icon, I tried everything else :)

Comment: @user3597446 You're welcome. :) I remember when I had updated iTunes a while back and it was all changed, it was super frustrating trying to figure out how to sync.